# Microstrategy using SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, microstrategy

I am trying to see what stored procedures in my database (using SSRS) are being used in the reports from MicroStrategy.

Is there a way to extract a list of reports from MicroStrategy?

Additionally, can I extract a list of which reports in MicroStrategy is using a stored procedure?

Comment: Please try to run `sp_who2` system SP in SSMS. It shows many interesting pieces of information: login, hostname, DBName, command, ProgramName, etc.

Comment: Between spWho and logging records from the sys.dm_exec)sessions table, youll either need to use a third party tool or build some logging of your own to get who is calling what procs. should be easy

Comment: You can get sql view of any report with REST api. Refer to this document,

https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/RESTSDK/Content/retrieve_sql_report_card.htm

Seems that you can get table info from it.

Answer (score 0):

In MicroStrategy, the list of reports can be extracted from Project Documentation, Enterprise Manager or using normal Search in Developer tool.

In case you are specifically trying to find MSTR reports that use a stored procedure, then you only need to look for Freeform SQL reports (or Logical Views), since they are one of few objects where MicroStrategy allows to specify stored procedures or custom SQL statements.